# The Facebook "Like" button doesn't show at all

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

New to coding, so bear with me if this is really basic!  I'm trying to add a FaceBook "like" button to my page.  I copied the code exactly as they describe on their instructions site.  I entered my page details, the desired width (it fit the limits of what they recommend for the features I selected in the generator), and so on, and then copied/pasted the code into my html.  I must be missing something. Their instructions were to paste this into the HTML, preferably just below the opening `<body>`, so I did:

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then they said to copy/paste the following wherever I wanted the button to show up, which I did:

```html
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/musicbyava" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

I refresh my page, and there's not a trace of anything in the place where the plugin is supposed to be.  Not a dot, not a line, not an error message, nada.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

There could be an array of problems why the script isn't displaying the like button. Without a url or copy of the outputted html, almost impossible to tell. If you are working on a local network and lose your internet connection, for example, boom, no FB Like box.

Taking a shot in the dark- This IS a javascript error. Errors in javascript are not displayed to the screen. Instead, they manifest themselves in a near infinite amount of ways, from omitting a single element after page load to loading a white screen.

If you are working with Chrome or Firefox, you can download an Web Developer extension. I recommend Firebug for Firefox, or Right Click and "Inspect Element" in Chrome (I think this ships with Chrome- otherwise it's  the Web Developer Extension)

Whichever tool you use, all errors with be outputted in the console of these environments.

And we're just getting started.

If this sounds like too much work, I recommend trying the above code on a different page to see if the page you are copy&pasting to has malformed html. Then it's back to the above advice.

Comment: Also make sure the code,  <div class="fb-like" ....</div> is between <tags> that are properly closed </tags>

Comment: OK, I uploaded the page to a server, so you can see what I'm trying to do.  http://studentaccess.emporia.edu/~asmith40/AVAwebsite/index.html
If it were a Javascript error, wouldn't FB be flooded with complaints, and be forced to fix it?  I would think that people use this plugin thousands of times per day.  I'm likelier to suspect that it's an error on MY part!  :)  
However, I pasted all the relevant plugin information into a blank HTML page with just a single line of text, and it still didn't work... (Click on the "Compositions" tab to see the blank page).  So...

Comment: OMG, once it's loaded to the server it started working!!  I guess it only works online.  I've been doing the coding in text documents and using Firefox to check my progress.  Holy cow... I learned something, I guess!

Comment: I had a feeling it was because the installation was your local server! For future reference, you CAN test facebook apps on your local environment, but it requires port forwarding on your router, and pointing the "A record" of a test domain to your local machine. But hey, you found a solution to the prob the easy way:) Good luck, and don't forget to ACCEPT my answer, as I did touch on the possiblity of Facebook not "seeing" your app on your local machine.

Comment: Also, clarification: the js error I was referring to was a javascript error on your part...:) That's why I suggested trying a web developer extension. 999/1000 problems can be solved with these tools. And learning how to use these tools, a rite of passge in itself, would benefit you greatly as you continue to build your website. Imagine being able to hone in on any piece of data on your site, and being able to troubleshoot/restyle it. It's a life saver!

Answer (score 5):

The reason it didn't work on your local machine but started to work magically on the server is this:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

the `//` in front of the code means that the browser should use the protocol in use at the time the script is being loaded... SO:

if you are running http://example.com facebook will load an unsecured one and if your using https://example.com then the script will be loaded from a secure server at facebook...

NOW here's where the magic happened... when loading from a local file your browser displays the URL as `file:///C:/mysite` so automatically the browser looks for a file called

```
file:///connect.facebook.net/....
```

That doesn't exist and IT FAILS miserably

guess what happened when you uploaded it to the server???

I'll let you figure that one out...

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and then added my domain url to my app settings in Facebook developer tools: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app_id]/settings/ -> Settings -> Basic

Answer (score -1):

for what sort of site are you using the fb like button for cms like joomla or wordpress i think best thing to use is http://sharethis.com/#sthash.OXTxyj48.dpbs good alternative and i used it many times if you like  try that out,after go to the site click **GET sharing tools** menu 
then you can go with it and past the code in your site ,

Comment: if you still like use fb code directory check whether you place the java script in correct place,and also check java script is enabled in your browser    hope this helps you...,

Comment: It's just a regular personal webpage, not part of a CMS.  Javascript is enabled.